# UIPickerView + TableViewCell + delegates and datasource

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I have Table view Controller and separate class which handles for me  tableviewcell. Inside the tableview cell I have pickerview.
How to implement delegate and datasource for pickerview which is in tableCell class but my delegate functions in tableview controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your tableView controller set a property on the tableview cells as they are created indicating that it is the delegate and datasource.

On the tableviewcell class you created just add a property that is an instance of you tableview controller. Like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyTableViewController * pickerDelegate;
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you can set that property to self

```
cell.pickerDelegate = self;
```

You might need to also set some sort extra property like a tag to distinguish between each cell. I would think another property on the tableviewcell like an NSIndexPath would do.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

1. Create outlet for UIPickerView in custom table view class:

   ```
   class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
       @IBOutlet var myPickerView: UIPickerView!
   }
   ```
2. Add delegate and datasource in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" in ViewController:

   ```
   class myViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {            
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! MyTableViewCell

           cell.myPickerView.dataSource = self
           cell.myPickerView.delegate = self

           return cell
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Even though you could do this, it feels like it's not a good separation of concerns. I disagree somewhat with the premise of the question as to whether this is a good practice at all. Alternatively, you could make the cell the delegate and assign the delegate to the cell via the interface builder, which would keep delegate code assigned to the cell.